# C++ regex with primary classes does not match

Tags: c++, regex, locale

In https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_traits/transform_primary the following example snippet is proposed:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
    std::locale::global(std::locale("en_US.UTF-8"));
    std::wstring str = L"AÀÁÂÃÄÅaàáâãäå";
    std::wregex re(L"[[=a=]]*", std::regex::basic);
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::regex_match(str, re) << '\n';
}
```

It is also said that it should output `true`. However, trying it with GCC 8 and Clang 7 on Debian and with the Clang that comes with a macOS High Sierra always gave `false` (you can directly test this with the "Run" button in the cppreference page).

One might say that the cppreference page is wrong, which is surely possible, however reading the documentation it also seems to me that `true` is the right output: all the characters in the string `str` are, as I understand it, in the primary collating class of `a`.

So the question is: who is right? The compilers or cppreference? And why?

Comment: If you instantiate a `regex_traits` and call `transform_primary` on the test string,  does it gives the same character duplicated ? Typically, it should return "xxxxxxxxxx" and not "xyxxyxxxxy" (with x or y implementation defined). The cppreference page is very poor here, since the documentation does not match the code on the bottom.

Comment: Also, please check https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/ecmascript

Comment: I've tested on my compiler and I do get `lookup_collatename` called (so the regex does check the collate for the class `a`), and `transform_primary` returns "DDDDDDDDDD" for me, yet the regex does not match. I'm not sure if it's a bug, I don't understand the source code for the regex_match function...

Answer (score 1):

Here's what the g++/libstdc++-9 implementation of `transform_primary` looks like:

```
template<typename _Fwd_iter>
string_type
transform_primary(_Fwd_iter __first, _Fwd_iter __last) const
{
  // TODO : this is not entirely correct.
  // This function requires extra support from the platform.
  //
  // Read http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2013-09/msg00117.html and
  // http://www.open-std.org/Jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2003/n1429.htm
  // for details.
  typedef std::ctype<char_type> __ctype_type;
  const __ctype_type& __fctyp(use_facet<__ctype_type>(_M_locale));
  std::vector<char_type> __s(__first, __last);
  __fctyp.tolower(__s.data(), __s.data() + __s.size());
  return this->transform(__s.data(), __s.data() + __s.size());
}
```

The comment says "is not entirely correct"; in my humble opinion the comment is not quite right. It should have said "this is totally wrong", because it is. It simply doesn't work.

The comment at the top of libc++-8 says:

```
// transform_primary is very FreeBSD-specific
```

Indeed it doesn't work on Linux at all (it returns an empty string for all characters). It could be working on a macOS, which is sort of a variant of FreeBSD, but I don't have one nearby to check. There could be a different bug lurking inside.

So the answer is, at least some of the compilers are wrong at least some of the time.